# getting wierd message on adding data to mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, api, postman

So i am trying to add data to backend in mongoDB cluster and through postman and when  add data the body in postman display's error 406 and "NULL" in console and when I try to add the same data again it diplay's the data in console and says "user already exist (when email already exist)" .

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const users = require('../models/userSchema');

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, age, mobile, work, desc } = req.body;

    if (!name || !email || !age || !mobile || !work || !desc) {
        res.status(400).send('Please fill all the fields');
    }
    try {
        const preuser = await users.findOne({ email: email });
        console.log(preuser);

        if (preuser) {
            res.status(400).json('User already exists');
        }
        else {
            const newuser = await new users({ name,email,age,mobile,work,desc});
            await newuser.save();
            res.status(201).json('User registered successfully');
            console.log(newuser, "user registered ");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(406).send(error);
    }
});
module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();

const port = 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(router);

app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);})
```

models.js

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    mobile: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    work: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const users = new mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
module.exports = users;
```

on addng the new data postman body shows wierd values like

```
{
    "code": 79,
    "codeName": "UnknownReplWriteConcern",
    "errInfo": {
        "writeConcern": {
            "w": "majorit",
            "wtimeout": 0,
            "provenance": "clientSupplied"
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "n": 1,
        "electionId": "7fffffff000000000000010c",
        "opTime": {
            "ts": {
                "$timestamp": "7127027872958513164"
            },
            "t": 268
        },
```

Comment: You already have a user with `Null` value in email field.

Comment: @ISAE hey i can't find where is it , sorry.